# Parse.com: query with date and UTC

Tags: javascript, date, parse-platform

I would like to delete object depending on date field.

For the moment, I succeed to delete events that have more than 1 day with this code:

```
function deleteOldEvents() {
    var today = new Date();
    var days = 1;
    var time = (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time));

    var query = new Parse.Query('Events');
        // All events have more than 1 days
        query.lessThan('date', expirationDate);

        query.find().then(function (Events) {
            Parse.Object.destroyAll(Events, {
                success: function(success) {}, error: function(error) {}
            });
    });
}
```

But now, I would like to delete events that have more than 12hours:

```
function deleteOldEvents() {
    var today = new Date();
    var time = (12 * 3600 * 1000);
    var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time));

    var query = new Parse.Query('Events');
        // All events have more than 12 hours
        query.lessThan('date', expirationDate);

        query.find().then(function (Events) {
            Parse.Object.destroyAll(Events, {
                success: function(success) {}, error: function(error) {}
            });
    });
}
```

This code delete events that have more than 14hours, not 12hours... maybe I have to use UTC ? I'm in France (UTC+2), that's maybe why that delete events more than 14 hours, not 12 hours?

How can I use UTC in javascript ?

Comment: Why not just correct for the offset for France in `expirationDate`? You already have `time` doing that for you...

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Yes but I didn't know that was the best choice 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, and you are right about the UTC issue - `Date.getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since 1st January 1970 in UTC time. For countries that are in a different timezone from UTC, you will need to incorporate an offset.

Use [`Date.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) to correct for the UTC discrepancy:

```
// getTimezoneoffset returns offset in minutes, so converting to milliseconds...
var offset = today.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time) + (offset));
```